# Is this the best way to make a timer auto-off feature for a CPU fan?

Tags: fan, time

This circuit is outside of a PC

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvdvRp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to make a fan that shuts off after a preset time depending on the capacitor value. The button restarts the timer. Is this the best way to do so?

Comment: What range of running times do you want?  I think that circuit will give a fairly short and poorly controlled time delay.

Answer (score 1):

With a few modifications this can be made to work. This will create a delay in the 15 minute range. I've added R4+R5 to provide "snap action" hysteresis so that Q2 doesn't overheat as it slowly turns off. R4 should be at least a 1W-2W resistor because it sees a fairly large pulse when the switch is pressed. As well as providing snap action R4 prevents C1 from welding the switch contacts when it is pressed.

R3 prevents leakage in Q1 from being multiplied by the gain of Q2.

If the power is interrupted during a timing cycle the B-E junction of Q1 can break down but that should be infrequent and low enough current not to cause a problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGIEj0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Frankly, though "best" .. not really. I'd use a 78L05, a PIC microcontroller such as PIC12F509 and a logic-level MOSFET. And maybe a flashing LED that increases in flash rate as it counts down for giggles.

Comment: All I know is that pins 3 and 4 are unused.

Answer (score 0):

Should be ok.  Three things:

1. You don't say what the Intel fan device current is.  You have around 11 mA of base current in Q2, which should be good for fan currents up to 200 mA.
2. You can get long timer periods with a smaller capacitor if you change Q1 to a small MOSFET, such as a 2N7000.  In this case, R1 and the timer cap are in parallel from the Q1 base to GND.
3. For a faster transition from on to off, add a large value resistor from the Q2 collector to the Q1 base.  This adds hysteresis to the circuit for a more crisp turn-off.  This must be a large resistor; too small and the circuit will latch on.